# Problem reading file and storing the data as array of structs - c

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a file contains data about students in the following format:

```
ID avg_scores first_name last_name city department
```

I created a struct of student with those fields:

```
typedef struct student {
    int student_id;
    int avg_scores
    char* first_name;
    char* last_name;
    char* city;
    char* department;
} *student;
```

I want to read the file line by line and store the data in array of students.
I'm getting in trouble with the char* fields.
what am I missing?

Also - why do I need to malloc those separately?
It didn't work otherwise and I don't really getting it - I also don't know the exact size of each item.

This is the function I created

```
student * getStudents(FILE * students, int numberOfStudents){
    student * studentsPtr = malloc(numberOfStudents * sizeof(student));

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfStudents; i++){
        studentsPtr[i] = malloc(sizeof(student));
        studentsPtr[i]->first_name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        studentsPtr[i]->last_name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        studentsPtr[i]->city = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        studentsPtr[i]->department = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        fscanf(students, "%d %d %s %s %s %s", &studentsPtr[i]->student_id,
               &studentsPtr[i]->avg_scores, studentsPtr[i]->first_name,
               studentsPtr[i]->last_name, studentsPtr[i]->city, studentsPtr[i]->department);
    }
    return studentsPtr;
}
```

Comment: It should work as long as 20 is big enough (make sure you're allowing space for the null terminator) and none of the cities or departments have spaces in their names.

Comment: What kind of trouble are you getting into?

Comment: Use `malloc(sizeof(struct student))`, instead of `malloc(sizeof(student))`.

Answer (score 2):

`char*` is nothing more than a pointer to a `char` type.  Pointers and arrays share the same syntax, but they are not the same.  You have defined pointers like `char* department;`, but they do not point to anything.  `malloc` gives you a chunk of memory to point at.

Since you have already came up with a maximum, you could avoid the individual `malloc`s by defining your struct like this:

```
typedef struct student {
    int student_id;
    int avg_scores
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    char city[20];
    char department[20];
} *student;
```

Now, you will not have to `malloc` the individual fields.  Now, you have arrays.